# How to use functions during a migration?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to migrate this model:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}
```

to this model:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string CryptoId { get; set; }
}
```

After running `Add-Migration`, this is what I got:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.projects", "cryptoId", c => c.String());
}
```

which I expanded into:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.projects", "cryptoId", c => c.String());

    // Populate cryptoId
    using (var db = new DbContext())
    {
        foreach (Project p in db.Projects)
        {
            Sql(string.Format
            (
                "UPDATE [dbo].[projects] SET [cryptoId] = '{0}' WHERE [id] = {1}",
                new CryptoId(p.Id), p.Id
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. When I run `Update-Database` I get following error message:

> The model backing the 'DbContext' context has changed since the database was created.

The error is obviously happening because I'm trying to access the out-of-date database with my up-to-date context, but I need to know the `Project.Id` in order to populate my `Project.CryptoId`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you done `Update-Database`, this applies your migrations to the database.

Comment: @BenRobinson, yes. The error message is what I get when I run `Update-Database`. I edited my question to add this little detail.

Comment: Have you tried doing your update in the `Seed` method, this runs after it has applied your migrations.

Comment: @BenRobinson, thanks for the hint, it works now. I was too focused on getting the migration file working, I didn't think about making use of the `Seed` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do this as two separate migrations - one to handle the schema, and one (where the schema now matches your code) to handle the alteration of the data...